# MVC Core bootstrap application theme in Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for the "proper way" to do this in MVC Razor...I'm using the bootstrap theme from 
http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/application

They show the following code:

```
<link href="dist/toolkit.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm thinking that the proper way should look like this for MVC Core Razor for the href:

The same goes for the src:

```
<script src="dist/toolkit.min.js"></script>

<script src=@Url.Content("dist/toolkit.min.js")></script>
```

Should I wrap the above 
in the following too?
@section scripts{}

ie. 
Is this necessary for the following?
    @section scripts{
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at that the default Templates provided?  Most everything is done through the default template and you can adjust to your hearts desire.  I assume you are using VS.NET or VS Code, it honestly doesn't matter which is used the scaffolding results in the same end layout, bower/gulp, or yeoman (vs code scaffolding), note default templates already have Bootstrap baked along with JS. Adding in other frameworks or features, using **bower** (client side) or **nuget**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Default Web</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position"
               asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
```

all located in the wwwroot folder... Gulp does most of the heavy lifting in the above case. Paths are coded in the gulpfile.js which does all of the "dynamics" of getting the script/css file set proper href/src items without having to resort to coding it with Razor..